# Написать программу, которая округляет вещественное число с любой точностью r

Tags: python

> Написать программу, которая округляет вещественное число с любой точностью r
>
> Пояснение: Например, у вас есть ряд чисел, записанных в левой колонке.
>   Вам нужно округлить их с точностью 0.025. Иначе говоря, числа нужно 
>   "перенести" в ближайший узел сетки, имеющей шаг 0.025. В результате 
>   получится правая колонка. Для двух чисел приведены окружающие
>   узлы сетки.
>
> ```
> 115.047   115.050    Сетка:    115.025  115.050  
> 115.093   115.100
> 115.514   115.525              115.500  115.525
> 115.090   115.100
> 114.912   114.900
> 114.904   114.900
> ```
>
> Указание: воспользуйтесь функцией Round.

Препод дал вот такое задание, нужна помощь экспертов.

Comment: И что у вас не получается?

Comment: Как округлить с точностью 0.025?
Я написал print("{x:1.3f}".format(x = round(115.047,1)))

Comment: Обычная нормализация в сетку. Делите на точность, округляете до целого, множите на точность. Какие проблемы-то? Если ноль  смещённый - вычитаете его в начале и прибавляете в конце.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

accuracy = 0.025
val = 115.047 
p = round(val / accuracy, 8)
res = round(math.ceil(p) * accuracy if p % 1 >= 0.5 else math.floor(p) * accuracy, 8)
```

Округление до восьми знаков нужно, чтобы избежать ошибок при работе с числами с плавающей точкой.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

num = 114.047
r = 0.025

res = math.ceil(num / r) * r
print("{res:1.3f}".format(res=res))
```

Comment: Это неверное решение. На числе 114.912 отработает неправильно.